# Widget: storing user preference

Tags: android, widget, preference

I'm trying to make a widget, for which the user has to provide a name. Based on that name, data is collected and shown. In the widget is a refresh button to refresh this data.

The problem is sharing this name between the configuration class and the AppWidgetProvider class. What I have tried:

- Just use an EditText in the widget. In the config class, set the name in the EditText, and retrieve it in the AppWidgetProvider class. ***This doesn't work, because I can't find a way to retrieve the text in the AWP.***
- Use SharedPreferences:

In the config class:

```
c = SelectWidgetStationActivity.this;

// Getting info about the widget that launched this Activity.
Intent i = getIntent();
Bundle extras = i.getExtras();
if (extras != null)
    awID = extras.getInt(AppWidgetManager.EXTRA_APPWIDGET_ID, AppWidgetManager.INVALID_APPWIDGET_ID);

SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(c);
prefs.edit().putString("widgetname" + awID, name);
prefs.edit().commit();
```

In the AWP class:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    if (intent.getAction().equals(ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER)) { //ACTION_WIDGET_RECEIVER is the action fired by the refresh button
        this.onUpdate(context, AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context), AppWidgetManager.getInstance(context).getAppWidgetIds(new ComponentName("com.app.myapp", "com.app.myapp.MyWidgetProvider")));
    }
}

@Override
public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
    SharedPreferences prefs = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(context);

for (int widgetId : appWidgetIds) {
        name = prefs.getString("widgetname" + widgetId, "N/A"));
    //more code
```

`name` keeps giving me "N/A". I've checked that `awID` and `widgetId` are equal.
This is probably due to the fact that I'm using different contexts? (Just guessing here)

So what is a way to solve this problem?

**Edit**
When I'm printing the contexts on screen I get the following:

- config class: `com.app.myapp.WidgetConfigActivity@40774d18`
- AWP class: `android.app.ReceiverRestrictedContext@406ad290`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just went through this again out of curiousity and noticed this:

```
prefs.edit().putString("widgetname" + awID, name);
prefs.edit().commit();
```

This gives you 2 different `Editor` instances.
What you do here is get one editor, put in the preference and leave it alone. Then you get a new (unchanged) editor and just commit it *(= no changes are written)*. Just tested that on a small project, doesn't commit correctly as intended.

So try to substitute the code with something like this:

```
Editor e = prefs.edit();
e.putString("widgetname" + awID, name);
e.commit();
```

or chain the commit in

```
prefs.edit().putString("widgetname" + awID, name).commit();
```

Comment: Okay. It worked! This is the first time I didn't store the Editor, just because I'm testing this stuff out and wanted to type faster (2 lines instead of 3). Well I guess the 'faster' bit didn't really work out ^.^ (Btw, I chained it now, making it 1 line =D )

Comment: Well, as said you can always chain editor methods like the last code snippet here. Thats just one line. (edit ehehe I'm too slow) :)

Answer (score 0):

You might try

```
SharedPreferences prefs = context.getSharedPreferences("someName", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
prefs.edit().putString("widgetname" + awID, name);
```

Make sure that `name` is not `null` when writing the preference. Otherwise you'll get `null` when reading it again which will return the default value "N/A" (like the key was not found).

Comment: I checked, `name` is certainly not `null`.

Answer (score -1):

```
public static final String PREFS_NAME = "MyPrefsFile";
private static final String PREF_USERNAME = "username";


SharedPreferences pref = getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE);
 //to access data from preference 

uid.setText(pref.getString(PREF_USERNAME, null));

//to set value in preference
   getSharedPreferences(PREFS_NAME, MODE_PRIVATE).edit()
                    .putString(PREF_USERNAME, uid.getText().toString()).commit();
```